# Why imported module function that is used once is called twice?

Tags: python-3.x, module, global-variables

I'm trying to create a **`Config`** module that contains function `options()`. That function gives the user specific options and allows them to type in which option they have chosen, then stores keyboard input into a variable that is used in other modules I have made. The code for the **`Config`** module is this:

```python3
def options():
   choices = {'1': 'Graph API Data', '2': 'Comparative Graphs', '3': 'Exit'}
   for choice, option in sorted(choices.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
       print(choice, option)
   Choice = eval(input('Select what you want to do'))
   return Choice 

    opt_number = options()
```

This module is called by another script:

```
import Config as conf

conf.options()
```

I want to assign `Choice` value to `opt_number`, but `opt_number = options()` causes the config module to be called twice when it's being called only once by my other script.

What actions should I take to eliminate calling function `options()` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read more about python [modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

You are importing module, which already calls that function by initializing, if you would remove line

```
conf.options()
```

from your another script, this should stop calling your function twice, it only would call that function once. Another way is to remove line

```
opt_number = options()
```

from the module Config.py.

Also, many other ways exists, for example using `opt_number = options()` in another function, so it wouldn't call `options()` until you would call that function. For example:

```
def take_action():
    opt_number = options()
```

inside Config.py module would initialize `opt_number` and call `options()` function only when `conf.take_action()` would be called in another script.

Comment: Thank you so much. I must have skimmed over that little detail.

Comment: @David if I answered your question you should [mark my answer as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), also comment section is dedicated for talking about problem, not thanking for answers (you can thank by upvoting). Read more about general rules [there](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).